# .htaccess link a server image directory to index.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using Apache and I have a sample web folder (on my localhost) like:

```
localhost/mypage/
```

In the folder, the files will be:

```
index.html
/images/sample.jpg
.htaccess
```

When I type the `localhost/mypage/images/sample.jpg`, is there anyway it will redirect to index.html with `.htaccess`?

Comment: Yes it is. look into mod_rewrite and rewriterules

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/sample.jpg
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L,QSA]
```

This will send requests to images/sample.jpg to index.html